# How to tidy data with a nested data frame?

Tags: r, functional-programming, tidyr, tidyverse, purrr

I am looking to tidy a nested data frame and I'm having some difficulties. I can reshape the data fine using one case, but I am looking to iterate over the entire data frame by case.

My data looks like this:

```
df <- tibble(
          case = c("a","a","b","b","c","c"),
          year = c(1990,2000,1990,2000,1990,2000),
          var1 = round(runif(6,0,1), 2),
          var2 = round(runif(6,10,20), 2)

)
```

I can perform the task I would like to with only one case using tidyr

```
 df %>% 
  filter( case == "a") %>%
  gather(var, value, -c(1:2)) %>%
  spread(year, value)
```

Output:

```
#      case  var  `1990` `2000`
#     <chr> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#    1 a     var1   0.850  0.540
#    2 a     var2  14.4   16.7
```

How can I use purrr or another functional programming tool to vectorize this operation and perform the same action with all of my cases and bind them into one data frame? Some combination of "nest" and "map"?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe `df %>% nest(-case) %>% mutate(output = map(data, ~gather(.x, var, val, -year) %>% spread(year, val))) %>% unnest()`, but it seems like there's a more elegant way to write that

Comment: Ah: `df %>% gather(var, val, var1:var2) %>% spread(year, val)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not gather the `case` column.

```
set.seed(1234)

df <- tibble(
  case = c("a","a","b","b","c","c"),
  year = c(1990,2000,1990,2000,1990,2000),
  var1 = round(runif(6,0,1), 2),
  var2 = round(runif(6,10,20), 2)
)

library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  gather(var, value, -c(1:2)) %>%
  spread(year, value)
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
#   case  var   `1990` `2000`
#   <chr> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 a     var1   0.110  0.620
# 2 a     var2  10.1   12.3  
# 3 b     var1   0.610  0.620
# 4 b     var2  16.7   15.1  
# 5 c     var1   0.860  0.640
# 6 c     var2  16.9   15.4
```

Comment: Thanks! I was way over thinking it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be using `dcast` from 'reshape2`package. But 1st it we need to gather`var1`and var2` columns using `gather`.

```
    library(tidyverse)
    library(reshape2)
    set.seed(1234)
    df <- tibble(
      case = c("a","a","b","b","c","c"),
      year = c(1990,2000,1990,2000,1990,2000),
      var1 = round(runif(6,0,1), 2),
      var2 = round(runif(6,10,20), 2)

    )
    # User gather to combine var1 and var2 and then apply dcast
    gather(df, var, val, var1:var2) %>% dcast(case+var ~ year, value.var = "val")
  # Result
  #    case  var  1990  2000
  #  1    a var1  0.11  0.62
  #  2    a var2 10.09 12.33
  #  3    b var1  0.61  0.62
  #  4    b var2 16.66 15.14
  #  5    c var1  0.86  0.64
  #  6    c var2 16.94 15.45
```